# Kivy text markup printing its own syntax

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I was testing out Kivy's markup feature. The basic outline of my test program is there are 4 labels and a button and **if the button is pressed, it changes the color of the first letter of label's text**. Now, the problem is when I press the button for the first time, it changes the color of first letter of all the label's text BUT from the second press onwards, it starts adding the markup syntax in the reverse manner at the beginning of the text. This is the program:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
import string

Builder.load_string(
'''
<CLabel@Label>:
    markup: True

<box>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Button:
        text: 'press'
        on_press: app.change()


    CLabel:
        id: a
        text: 'abcd'

    CLabel:
        id: b
        text: 'efgh'

    CLabel:
        id: c
        text: 'ijkl'

    CLabel:
        id: d
        text: 'mnop'
'''
)

class box(BoxLayout):
    pass

class main(App):
    def change(self):
        for lol in string.lowercase[:4]:
            self.root.ids[lol].text = '[color=#E5D209]{}[/color]{}'.format(self.root.ids[lol].text[0], self.root.ids[lol].text[1:])

    def build(self):
        return box()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main().run()
```

This is the output after the first press:
[image]

This is the output after the second press:
[image]

This is the output after the third press:
[image]

I hope you get the problem now. The markup syntax at the beginning of the text keeps on increasing with the number of times the button is pressed.

I thought maybe it was the loop's fault. So I removed the loop and tested with only the first widget. Same problem.

Now here's the catch- when I change the color by changing the contents of the change function like this:

```
def change(self):
    self.root.ids.a.text = '[color=#E5D209]a[/color]bcd'
    self.root.ids.b.text = '[color=#E5D209]e[/color]fgh'
    self.root.ids.c.text = '[color=#E5D209]i[/color]jkl'
    self.root.ids.d.text = '[color=#E5D209]m[/color]nop'
```

It works perfectly fine. But by doing this method, I'll have to copy paste a lot of lines. This was just a snippet of what I'm working on. The real project I'm working on has more than 15 labels and copy pasting for each and every label is tiresome. It'd be much better if it is done by a loop. It makes work short and precise.

After this, out of frustration I tried with get_color_from_hex method by this code:

```
self.root.ids[lol].text[0] = self.root.ids[lol].text[0].get_color_from_hex('#E5D209')
```

But I ended up getting an error message saying:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'color'
```

I'd be really glad if someone came with a way to change the color of first letter of the text of god knows how many labels. :'(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The markup is part of the string stored in `text`. So the second time you run the loop, indeed the first character (`[`) gets inserted in between the markup tags, messing up the parsing.

What you want to do could be achieved by storing the raw text in another `StringProperty`, let's call it `_hidden_text`. Then, in the loop, you can set

```
self.root.ids[lol].text = '[color=#E5D209]{}[/color]{}'.format(self.root.ids[lol]._hidden_text[0], self.root.ids[lol]._hidden_text[1:])
```

In this way you avoid reusing the added markup.
Of course you may want to set up bindings for making the assignment `_hidden_text`→`text` automatic.

#### Edit:

Add this class definition:

```
class CLabel(Label):
    hidden_text = StringProperty('')
```

then change the kv style for `CLabel` to

```
<CLabel>:
    markup: True
    text: self.hidden_text
```

and each use of `CLabel` should look like

```
CLabel:
    id: a
    hidden_text: 'abcd'
```

Comment: I hate to say it but I don't have much experience with working with properties. And also when I do work with properties, I run into problems far beyond my understanding. :\ But I kinda found a work around for my program without using StringProperty. Here, have a look: http://pastebin.com/25KmXnMu

Now, the problem is I have to type the text twice. :\ Under the labels, when I tried `hidden_text: self.text`, I ran into the same problem as before. Even when I assigned `hidden_text` to `self.root.ids[lol].text` under the for loops, I had the same problem.

Comment: I tried using StringProperty here http://pastebin.com/2ay2KvP3. Is this the way to use StringProperty? The output still has the problem mentioned in the question though.

Comment: @ParthibBiswas added example for how to use `StringProperty` (it should be a property of the `CLabel` class), and showed how to not have to double-type the text. BTW, if you need your `CLabel` class to behave like `Label` (i.e. text should be set through `text`), have a look at `AliasProperty`.

Comment: It worked! I surely will look into AliasProperty. While doing that, I have to start practicing more with other properties as well. Thank you.