# Kivy markup messing up opening square bracket

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

Suppose a Label widget has a text 'abcd[', it prints out the correct thing on the output screen as expected. But when I set the markup for that Label widget to True, it prints out 'abcd[[/color]'. How do I overcome this? I found out one possible fix by adding '\n' after the opening bracket in the text. But since I have many widgets in a row close to each other, the newline is pretty visible and it looks kinda ugly.

For this example, I'm using Button instead of Label.

This is the output for

```
Button:
    markup: True
    text: 'abcd\n['
```

[image]

And this is the output for

```
Button:
    markup: True
    text: 'abcd\n[\n'
```

[image]

As I said, adding a newline makes it look ugly and the difference in text level between the nearby widgets look very visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved by using `escape_markup` or replacing '[' with '&bl;'.

**Method 1**: Using the `escape_markup`.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = ('''
#:import escape kivy.utils.escape_markup
Label:
    markup: True
    text: 'abcd{}'.format(escape('['))
''')

class mainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainApp().run()
```

**Method 2**: Character replacement.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = ('''
#:import escape kivy.utils.escape_markup
Label:
    markup: True
    text: 'abcd&bl;'
''')

class mainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainApp().run()
```

Now, if you want to change color of '[' you have to do it like this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

kv = (
'''
#:import escape kivy.utils.escape_markup
<L>:
    markup: True
    text: self.hidden_text

<B>:
    Button:
        text: 'press'
        on_press: root.lel()

    L:
        id: lol
        hidden_text: 'abcd{}'.format(escape('['))
        markup: True
B
'''
)

class L(Label):
    hidden_text = StringProperty('')

class B(BoxLayout):
    def lel(self):
        self.ids.lol.text = '{}[color=#E5D209]{}[/color]'.format(self.ids.lol.hidden_text[:4], self.ids.lol.hidden_text[4:])

class color(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    color().run()
```

Notice what I did in lel() in B class. To change to color of '[', I typed hidden_text[4:] instead of hidden_text[4]. This is because when you do escape('['), all it does is it replaces '[' by '&bl;'. So, when you use hidden_text[4], you'll get this output:

[image]

But if you use hidden_text[4:], it covers the characters after & until it reaches the semi-colon.

To know why I used StringProperty on the Label's text, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36772411/kivy-text-markup-printing-its-own-syntax).